# Android API 24 : split screen - activity does not start back stack's activity when destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-7.0-nougat, split-screen

I have been struggling with this bug for days. This bug happens under rare but likely condition and I just cannot find why this is happening.

### What happens is:

In split screen mode (my app at top and another at bottom), when certain activity quits, back-stack activity's (in my case, mostly MainActivity) `onStart()` is never called, and split screen mode *looks like* it's ended because my app is dead, but the overview button still looks like I'm in split screen mode and when I tap the split screen button, my MainActivity's `onStart()` is finally called, and it's back to split screen mode again.

### The log looks like

`MainActivity onStop()
ProblematicActivity onCreate()
...
ProblematicActivity onDestroy()
//and nothing!`

### This does *not* happen under these conditions:

1. When the problematic activity is called in not-split-screen mode, but finishes in split-screen mode. (both `resumed` and `paused`)
2. When the problematic activity is called in split-screen mode, but my app is tapped (i.e, my activity is in `resumed` state)

### This happens only when:

1. Problematic activity is started in split-screen mode, and my activity is not tapped (i.e., my activity is in `paused` state)

I've checked activity lifecycle callback thoroughly (at least I think so) and looked into logs many times but I just cannot figure out why BackStack activity is not called.

I've tried searching but there were no much helpful information. Did anyone had any experience/problem similar to mine?

Thanks.

### additional Info

My activity stack looks like this

MainActivity
Activity 2
Activity 1
Fragment 1

Server sends my app to start a feature, then it starts Activity 2, it starts activity 1, and Fragment 1 is in activity 1 (what user really sees is fragment 1) Activity & fragments are well-destroyed until Activity2. But From there, MainActivity (or no matter what activity it is) is not visible since AndroidSystem never calls `onStart`.

Comment: "when certain activity quits... and my activity is not tapped (i.e., my activity is in paused state)" -- in what circumstances would this activity "quit" when it "is not tapped"?

Comment: @CommonsWare It receives a signal from server. This activity can start and end in two ways: one, user starts/ends it. Two, server tells them to stars/end a activity. The behaviour is pretty much like android phone call. It can quit even when screen is off.

Comment: It would not surprise me if this is a bug in Android's multi-window implementation.

Comment: do you think I should report this to Google? Or in other words, is this a problem worth bothering them?

Comment: If you can create an app that can reliably reproduce the problem (given a certain set of actions on the part of the tester), I suggest [filing an issue](https://b.android.com). If, OTOH, while the problem happens, you cannot reproduce it reliably, while you file an issue, you may be frustrated with the results.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll try. Thank you a lot for attention & advices.

Comment: @CommonsWare it was a defect in android os. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it was a defect in Android OS.

Google's response is as below

> Hi,
>   We have passed this defect on to the development team and will update this issue with more information as it becomes available.
>   Thanks

Issue link:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231337&can=1&q=reporter%3Aadobecs5&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened